# REST service return collection of XML documents

Tags: rest

We are writing a REST service to query for PDF files. The service consumer wants the metadata for those PDFs, not the actual PDF. The metadata for happens to be stored as an XML document, one XML document for each PDF resource. They resource and the resource's metadata are completely different files.

What should the query response look like?

Typically we use JSON for request/response bodies. Should the response body be a JSON object that contains a collection of URLs, where each URL links to a metadata document? This seems pretty clean, but causes a lot unnecessary network traffic because the consumer must send a GET request for each metadata document.

Should the XML of the metadata documents be embedded in the response body's JSON object? (yuck!)

Is there a solution is both clean and efficient?

Comment: Is all your "REST API" doing is providing a link for them to download the meta data for PDFs, or is this part of a larger API?

Comment: Also, is the endpoint for a single PDF, or is it a single endpoint with a GET/POST parameter specifying which pdfs they need the meta data for?

Comment: @gre The GET resource endpoint currently fetches 1 XML document. E.g. Sending the GET request"http://host/metadata/123" would get a response of one XML document.

Comment: I would just return the XML document as a download. It's not really a "RESTful API", it's just an HTTP API for getting document meta data. You don't need to nest the payload in JSON/XML unless you really want to.

Comment: For multiple, send a ZIP

Comment: <Saw the additional comments after I wrote this> Should the "REST API" return the XML contents of the metadata documents? Should it return only links to fetch each metadata document? Should it provide both? Should the service produce a "multipart/mixed" media type where each part is a single XML document? These are the questions I'm looking to answer.

Comment: I think you're right that nesting the payload in an XML or JSON response would look silly, so my answer essentially says: "just have them download the file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some clarifying comments, I'm going to suggest that you don't write a "RESTful" API. You don't need one. You don't have objects that you need to interact with in any complex way. You don't have state that needs to be affected (REST means Representational State Transfer).

You just need an HTTP API. Just return the XML file. You can also provide an endpoint to get multiple XML documents ZIPed, if you want.

So do something like this:

- `/api/host/123` - download the PDF file (`Content-Type: application/pdf`) - You didn't say if you already have an endpoint for PDFs, but if you did want one, this is how I would structure it.
- `/api/host/123/metadata` - download the XML metadata (`Content-Type: text/xml`)
- `/api/host/bulk_metadata` - download a ZIP of the metadata for file IDs listed in a POST parameter (`Content-Type: application/zip`)

Use `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="{filename}.{pdf|xml|zip}"` to tell browsers to download the content to disk rather than displaying it inline.

Comment: Thanks you Greg. I appreciate it. I've put some options (including yours) out to the team. I'll post an update when we decide on the approach.

Comment: @ahoffer what did you choose?

Comment: I moved off the project in January and I don't remember what we went with. I think we went with sending back the list of hyperlinks to individual resources and letting the client request the resources one-by-one. The powers-that-decided that wouldn't be a lot of network traffic because eventually the page size would limit the number hyperlinks returned at once.